# How to i get Month & Year from SQL in Varchar Type

Tags: sql, t-sql

I Already Created Table (commercials) Column (**MyDate**) "Varchar(255)"

I Have some manual entries like:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
01-05-2019
02-05-2019
15-06-2019
16-06-2019
```

Now i want to select Only One Month and year. like

```
05-2019 or 06-2019
```

Please tell me how i can select only Month and year from this column.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the database you are using. For example in pl-sql, you would probably use to_char, in t-sql you could instead use convert. As such, please provide a bit more information.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any conversion among data types, since you want to extract a string from string, and to extract the part with `mm-yyyy` format pattern, just use `substring()` function as below :

```
select distinct substring(replace(MyDate,' ',''), 4, 7) as "Month-Year"
  from myTable;

Month-Year
----------
05-2019
06-2019
```

By the way, consider using `replace(MyDate,' ','')` (`trim(MyDate)` *for version 2017+*) against the probabilty of having space within the strings.

Comment: Thanks bro. Can you please tell me how to i select any One Month and year, like 05-2019 I don't want to select another month

Comment: you're welcome dear @ALIImran , but I couldn't  exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: When i use this query then Sql Showing All Records. but i wanna show only one month record like May 2019 (05-2019) I don't want to show another Month

Comment: @ALIImran hm well, just replace local variable `@MyDate` with `MyDate` column from your table(namely `myTable`)

Comment: @ALIImran if you need to get unique output for each month just use `distinct`.

Comment: Bro everything is okay But i am not getting result what i want. I already use search Query `SELECT * FROM commercials WHERE MyDate LIKE '___05-2019' ORDER BY MyDate DESC` This query showing Well Result. But this is Search query. I want to Use Proper Query. who give me Perfect Result.

Answer (score 0):

Use string operations:

```
select right(col, 4) as yyyy,
       right(col, 7) as mmyyyy,
       substring(col, 4, 2) as mm
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, Can you please tell me how to i select Some Selected Month and year, like 05-2019 I don't want to select another month.

Answer (score 0):

Using DISTINCT on Only MM-YYYY part of your data will return a MM-YYYY combination only once as per your requirement. Sample script is shown below-

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(MyDate, 7)
FROM commercials
```